# Check if Record Exists Else do Insert

Tags: database, asp-classic

I am trying to check if a record exist in the database. If it exists discard insert function. And if the record does not exist insert.

I'm getting the opposite effect.

```vb
<% 
Set OBJdbConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
OBJdbConnection.open MM_Listings_STRING

'1. Check if contractor is linked
SQLQuery1 = "Select * FROM Agent_Contractor WHERE ContractorID = " &_
Request.Form("ContractorID") & " AND AgentID = " & Session("AgentID") 

Set Results = OBJdbConnection.Execute(SQLQuery1)

'1. If linked response write. 
If Results.EOF  Then
  Response.Write "Contractor Already Linked"
else
  '1. Insert
  SQLQuery3 = "INSERT INTO Agent_Contractor (" &_
  "ContractorID, " &_
  "AgentID) VALUES (" &_
  Request.Form("ContractorID") & ", " &_
  Session("AgentID") & ")"

  OBJdbConnection.Execute(SQLQuery3)    
  Response.Write "Contractor Linked successfully."
end if
%>
```

Comment: Your code is full of security holes.

Comment: What @ElGavilan is saying is your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection consider using the `ADODB.Command` object to build a Parametrised Query, instead of using `ADODB.Connection`'s `Execute()` method.

Comment: Also if you are just checking for the existence of the contractor there is no need to return all the fields from `Agent_Contractor` table consider using `SELECT NULL FROM Agent_Contractor ...` the query will still work but will not return any field, just `NULL` which still signifies the existence of the record without the overhead of using `SELECT *` (Assuming your using SQL Server for your db, not specified in your question or tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You statements are backwards in your code.

"If either the BOF or EOF property is True, there is no current record." as per [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821459(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821459%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

So the contractor is NOT linked if Results.EOF are true.

Comment: @user3501463 This is the correct answer your issue regardless of the method you have used is your check for data in the `ADODB.Recordset`. You should be using `If Not Results.EOF Then` (Your logic is back to front at present). +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` condition in `WHERE`. Take a look at the sample code below:

```
"INSERT INTO Agent_Contractor (ContractorID, AgentID) " &_
"SELECT '" & Request.Form("ContractorID") & "', '" &_
Session("AgentID") & "' FROM Agent_Contractor WHERE " &_
"NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM Agent_Contractor WHERE ContractorID = '" &_
Request.Form("ContractorID") & "' AND AgentID = '" & Session("AgentID") & "')"
```

I'm not sure if I get the cancatination right for I can't run it but I'm trying to point out the logic. You can make an adjustment to that.

Comment: We shouldn't be encouraging bad practice, this statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection. At least mention this in your answer. Also don't think reversing the logic in the SQL is the way to fix this issue.